# Using the closeEvent in a qt application does not close it

Tags: qt, quit

I am learning qt, and experimenting with examples from a textbook.

The original textbook code has the following, set up to save and close on the x button:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if (okToContinue()) {
        writeSettings();
        event->accept();
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}
```

i experimented with a simple exit in its menu - and it works:

```
void MainWindow::close()
{
    if (okToContinue()) {
        QApplication::quit();
    }
}
```

But I want to take advantage of the already written closeEvent, so i replaced the code above with

```
void MainWindow::close()
{
    QCloseEvent *event = new QCloseEvent();
    closeEvent(event);
}
```

I get the checking for changes and saving app, implemented through the okToContinue function. But the application does not close.

i tried to follow through debugging and.. with my small understanding, it seems that there is a close signal being sent...

I don't have a good understanding of this, can somebody please help me figure out what am i doing wrong and how to fix it ?

(the sample code is from C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4, chapter 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to reimplement MainWindow::close() in your subclass. 
From the Qt Docs:

> ...QCloseEvent sent when you call QWidget::close() to close a widget
>   programmatically...

So you just have to reimplement MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) if you want to control this event.

This event fires when you click `x` or call close() from the code.

Answer (score 2):

The `closeEvent` and related methods don't actually execute the action that happens when a given event is received. They merely allow you to act on the event and perhaps disable its further processing. The closing of the window is done within `QWidget::event`, where `closeEvent` is called from.